# Open Outlook with pywin32 in fullsize/fullscreen

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

I can open a new instanz of Outlook with pywin32 but nit wonnt open in full screen, always like 80% of the screen. Is there a function i miss?

This is my code:

```
import win32com.client as win32

def olOpenNew():
    outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(6).Display()

olOpenNew()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the `WindowState` property of the `Explorer` class to the `olMaximized` value, for example:

```
Sub MaximizeWindows() 
 Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer 
 Dim myOlExps As Outlook.Explorers 
 Set myOlExps = Application.Explorers 
 For x = 1 To myOlExps.Count 
   myOlExps.Item(x).WindowState = olMaximized 
 Next x 
End Sub
```